# Invalid status code not found error while using New-AzRoleAssignment

Tags: azure-rbac

I created an application in azure active directory like below

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le9l3.png)

I am trying to add a Storage Blob Data Contributor role assignment for azure active directory service principal to operate on the storage account level through PowerShell

whenever i try to run the below command

```
   New-AzRoleAssignment -Serviceprincipal <Serviceprincipal name> -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Contributor" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionsID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegrp name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageacc name>"
```

I am getting the error as below.please help me with the solution

> New-AzRoleAssignment: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got same error like below.***

[image]

To resolve this issue check whether you have provided correct endpoints and service principal ID try to use this scope in storage account endpoint like below.

***In your storage account -> Under setting -> Endpoint -> Storage account resource***

[image]

***When I try to run the below command, I got result successfully.***

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -Serviceprincipal <Serviceprincipal name> -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Contributor" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionsID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegrp name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageacc name>"
```

[image]

To check in portal, finally `Storage Blob Data Contributor role` is added successfully like below.

[image]